# Does (doc ....) display the document text string of non-core, user defined functions?

Tags: clojure

I have:

```
(defn my-add [a b]
   "takes two numbers and adds them together"
   (+ a b))
```

this function works as expected:

```
(my-add 3 4) => 7
```

but when I do:

```
(doc my-add)
```

all I get is:

```
user/my-add
([a b])
nil
```

Whereas if I do 'doc' on a clojure/core function:

```
(doc str)
```

I get all the information I would expect, including the text:

```
clojure.core/str
([] [x] [x & ys])
With no args, returns the empty string. With one arg x .....[etc]
```

Why won't my user-defined function with document text also display? Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. You have the docstring in the `fn` body.

Try:

```
(defn my-add
  "takes two numbers and adds them together"
  [a b]
  (+ a b))
```

Comment: Thanks! I have also seen in a map placed after the doc string such as {:added 1.6 :author "John"}. How do I then access those from the (doc) function?

Comment: @user3231690 those maps are metadata maps attached to the var. `(meta #'clojure.core/map)`

Comment: I see, so how can I get at them?